# Saving a list of entities to the db - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I think I almost have this working, but I cant figure out how to finish.

Model:

```
 public class Location
 {
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string SiteCode { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int IncidentId { get; set; }
  }
```

View Model

```
    public List<Location> LocationList { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddRecord(RecordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Location location;
            foreach (var loc in model.LocationList)
            {
                location = new Location
                {
                    PersonId = model.PersonId,
                    SiteCode = loc.SiteCode,
                    IncidentId = loc.IncidentId
                };
            }

            using (var db = new MyEntities())
            {
                db.Order.AddObject(incident);
                db.Location.AddObject(location);
                db.Comment.AddObject(comment);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

The line `db.Location.AddObject(location);` is receiving empty.  How do I get the location list from the foreach, to the db?

Comment: Is the action decorated with `[HttpPost]`? Also, what's `TrespassEntities` supposed to be?

Comment: Yes it Post.  Name changed to MyEntities, it is the EF db connection.

Comment: You should create a repo project to handle database related stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're so close!

```
// create a new list of your entity Location (may not be in namespace Data)
var locationList = new List<Data.Location>();
foreach (var loc in model.LocationList)
{
    var location = new Data.Location
    {
        PersonId = model.PersonId,
        SiteCode = loc.SiteCode,
        IncidentId = loc.IncidentId
    };
    locationList.Add(location);
}

using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
    db.Order.AddObject(incident);

    foreach (var item in LocationList)
    {
        db.Location.AddObject(location);
    }
    db.Comment.AddObject(comment);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

OR: since you already have the LocationList on your model, use that instead

```
using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
    db.Order.AddObject(incident);

    foreach (var loc in model.LocationList)
    {
        var location = new Data.Location
        {
            PersonId = model.PersonId,
            SiteCode = loc.SiteCode,
            IncidentId = loc.IncidentId
        };

        db.Location.AddObject(location);
    }
    db.Comment.AddObject(comment);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use addrange.

```
db.YourTable.AddRange(YourList)
db.SaveChanges();

db.Location.AddRange(LocationList)
db.SaveChanges();
```